# Using increments in a for loop

Tags: julia

I am trying to run a for loop in Julia using bounds for integration where `fI` and `r` are arrays of the same length. I know this is incorrect, but this is the gist of what I want to do.

```
    a = zeros(1:length(fI))
    for i = 1:length(fI)
      a[i] = (fI[i+1] - fI[i])/(r[i+1] - r[i])
    end
```

How can I set increments of n+1 in Julia? Haven't had any luck finding the answer elsewhere.

Just let me know if I can clarify anything. I'm still pretty new to the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not completely sure what you want to do, but it looks as you want to create a new variable based on the difference between elements in the other variables. If that is your use case, you can use `diff`, e.g.

```
fI, r = rand(10), rand(10)
a = diff(fI) ./ diff(r)
```

Comment: This seems to work more how I wanted. 
I should have clarified, fI is actually F(r). For every two points of r, an array of 1000 elements, I want to find the difference of F(r) between them.

Comment: Something like `r = rand(1000); f(x) = x^2; diff(f.(r))` ?

Comment: F(r) and r are given from a data file. So I literally want the equation I gave above. From the array I want the first value subtracted from the second value and so on. It's part of integration so there has to be an easy way to do this, I just haven't been able to find it.

Comment: But doesn't the code in my answer literally give the result of the equation you gave above?

Comment: Hmm, yes. Think I needed to step away and come back to it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

Ranges are specified by `start:stepsize:end`. Thus the answer is `for i = 1:(n+1):length(fI)`.

Comment: Okay, what should I define as n then? Should that also use `n = 1:length(fI)` ?

Comment: with `1:n:length(fI)`, `n` is just how many terms you want to skip. I don't know your problem so I don't know how you want to set `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will crash since for the last "i" you access beyond the array length

```
fI[i+1] = fI[length(fI)+1]


a = zeros(1:length(fI))
for i = 1:length(fI)
  a[i] = (fI[i+1] - fI[i])/(r[i+1] - r[i])
end
```

Maybe you intend the following

```
n = length(fI) - 1
a = zeros(1:n)
for i = 1:n
  a[i] = (fI[i+1] - fI[i])/(r[i+1] - r[i])
end
```